# How to save email adresses having weird, rare format?

Tags: contacts, email, contact-summary-editor

One of our contacts has a weird, rare email format:

```
name-@web.de
```

I did not know, that having a `-` in front of `@` is even possible. It is the correct adress and the adress reaches its owner. Regardless of how clever it is, having such an adress, I do have the problem: I cannot save it in the contact field. An error message: invalid email adress appears.

**Does anybody know how to force civicrm to accept the weird email format?**

---

using:

- CiviCRM 5.31.0.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the email validation inside CiviCRM does not like that pattern. If it is a valid email address that validation would have to be changed. You can do that yourself with a PR (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/contributing/) or at least raise it as an issue (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/issue-tracking/#guidelines). Thanks!